# Generate a BigInteger from ModPow result

Tags: java, c#, biginteger

Imagine we have `a=a.ModPow(b,c)`
The exact code may be different in different languages of course but it is `a^b mod c`.
How a satisfying `a` could be generated having `b` and `c`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to _solve the equation_ `x^b mod c = a`?  This is as much a math question as anything else.

Comment: Solving the equation for x indeed. With few tools (methods) in programming languages (Pow, ModPow, etc) each with limitations (eg the int exponent in Pow)

Comment: You need to have the factorization of `c`. Integer factorization alone is a hard problem.